# not able to select hidden link - selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I have to select web link when i mouse hover to particular frame in  the webpage, the button(link to next page) will be visible.

```
WebElement mainElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(<frame xpath >));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(mainElement);
WebElement button1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='currentSkills']/div[1]/div/a"));
builder.moveToElement(button1).click().perform();
```

I am still unable to select the particular link
when i execute, the following error am getting
`org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException`: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 131 milliseconds

But when i hover mouse pointer to the particular frame during AUT(just to move to particular frame without clicking anything), then test is executing sucessfully.

I know this can be handled by JS. But i want to find out is there any solution within selenium webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some of the drivers for the various browsers, sometimes custom actions like this won't work unless you explicitly enable native events at the time you create the driver:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();   
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);     
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

or another method of setting it at the time you create DesiredCapabilities for a remote driver

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Action Chains I have always found it more reliable to perform all the actions in the same chain. As such, rather than 'pausing' to find the now revealed element, try doing so within the chain.

```
WebElement mainElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(<frame xpath >));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(mainElement).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='currentSkills']/div[1]/div/a"))).click().perform();
```

Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark... its worked as desired in chrome... but still getting some problem same kind of problem in FF...

Comment: To be honest, I've experienced similar problems myself between the two browsers - Chrome will just work with something similar to the above but Firefox might have issues.   So are you seeing the same exception in Firefox or is something else happening?

Comment: same exception in firefox... :-(

Comment: Just a curiousity, if you watch the test proceed in your browser, do you see the wanted element appear, even if only for a brief second?

Comment: You may need to enable native events on your firefox driver to get this to work. Right before you create your driver, modify the profile you hand over to it

`FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();`     `profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);`    `driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);`

Comment: Up vote for Andy as this was going to be my next suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

My View here is Need to Perform Mouse Over on the Object to make it visible and then click on that element.

```
WebElement mainElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(<frame xpath >));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

builder.moveToElement(mainElement).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='currentSkills']/div[1]/div/a"))).build().perform();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='currentSkills']/div[1]/div/a")).click();
```

Please Let me know is the above scripting is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();   
         profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);     
         driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);    

WebElement searchBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
    WebElement searchBtn1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(searchBtn).moveToElement(searchBtn1).click().build().perform();
```